# Tomcat cannot connect to MySQL on localhost

Tags: mysql, tomcat, ip, connection, localhost

I have deployed an application on my Tomcat server with JDBC resources defined. What is puzzling me is that I can connect to the database (which is running locally on the server) only using the server's IP. When I change the resource host to localhost (or 127.0.0.1) then MySQL rejects the connection. I don't want to be connection via the server's IP but rather locally.

What do I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Operating System? Are you using a firewall? Which interfaces is MySQL listening on?

Comment: That is on Ubuntu. I am using firewall but 3306 is open - I can connect to the MySQL server from outside via the server's IP. The problem is that Tomcat only connects to MySQL using the server's IP and not localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL treats localhost connections and 127.0.0.1 connections and '%' connections differently. Your user needs to be granted access specifically to connect to localhost or 127.0.0.1 or both.